# What is the meaning of these two words in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The text is from the novel "Salem's Lot":

> It was the tenth of
> January, just about the time most folks are learning to live comfortably with all
> the New Year’s resolutions they broke, and there was one hell of a northeaster
> blowing outside. ***Six inches*** had come down before dark and it had been going
> hard and heavy since then. Twice we had seen Billy Larribee go by high in the
> cab of the town plow, and the second time Tookey ***ran him out*** a beer—an act of
> pure charity my mother would have called it, and my God knows she put down
> enough of Tookey’s beer in her time.

What is the meaning of "six-inches" and "ran him out" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Six inches** means "six inches of snow." Note the reference to the "town plow" later.

**Ran him out** means "ran out with." Tookey ran out to give the plow driver a beer.

Comment: I don't understand why he had to run out with a cup of beer though? There was no emergency or anything.

Comment: There *was* an emergency. Snow was falling very quickly, so much that the plow driver needed to clear the same road twice. If Tookey had walked out with a beer when he saw the plow, it would have already passed by. Anyway, 'ran' is not necessarily literal. "Run me over to the next town please." "Run that past me again."

Comment: One last thing, "go by high" in the context means he was sitting up high on the big plow machine and driving it,right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws "go by high" is not really a single chunk; it's "(go by) (high in the cab (of the town plow))".  But yes, he drove the plow past them and the driver's seat in the plow was situated significantly higher than a normal vehicle's driver's seat.  (Also, it was probably a can or a bottle of beer, not a cup.)